# WP Query get and id by $_GET and change it to a CPT link

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to make a query to get an id and make a return of a cpt custom link. Here's my code but cannot end it:

```
<?php
require_once('wp-load.php');

    $args = array(
        'post_type' =>  'catalogos',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'id' => $_GET['id'],
    );

    $query= new WP_Query($args);

    $link = get_field('link');

    if(isset($_GET['id'])){
        wp_redirect(home_url()"/".$link."/");
    }



?>
```

Comment: `$_GET['id']` Are you getting page id or custom id?

Comment: it is a page id, that's id is on the link, i need to take the id and add it to a custom post type link

Answer (score 1):

```
http://yoursite.com/?id=your_page_id eg:2

 $args = array(
                'post_type' =>  'catalogos',
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'id' => $_GET['id'],
            );

            $query= new WP_Query($args);

            if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
            while ( $query->have_posts() ){
              $query->the_post();
            $post_id = get_the_ID();
               $link = get_field('link');
             if($link){
                wp_redirect(home_url()"/".$link."/?id=".$post_id);
            }
            }
          }
          wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: I need to add the id to the link.

Comment: updated the ans . you can use also $_GET['id'] instead of get_the_ID(),

Answer (score 0):

Make sure if there is 'id' parameter
https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query